# A matroid problem inspired by a linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matroids

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A = (v_{ij})$, with $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$, be an $m$ by $n$ array of elements of $V$ (so that for each $i$, $j$ as above, $v_{ij} \in V$). Let us also assume that $m \geq n$.

Consider the following operation. Select from each row (resp. column) of $A$ an element, and then calculate the rank of the $m$ (resp. $n$) chosen elements of $A$, which means the maximal number of these $m$ (resp. $n$) elements which are linearly independent. Define the row-rank (resp. column-rank) of $A$, to be the maximum of all these ranks, as you go over all possible choices of $m$ (resp. $n$) elements of $A$, with one from each row (resp. column) of $A$.

Let $J \subseteq \underline{n}:= \{1,\ldots,n\}$ be a non-empty subset. Define $A^J$ to be the $m$ by $|J|$ subarray of $A$ whose columns are precisely the columns of $A$ indexed by elements of $J$.

Hypothesis: $\operatorname{row-rank}(A^J) \geq |J|$ for any non-empty subset $J \subseteq \underline{n}$.

Question: does it follow from the setup and hypothesis above that $\operatorname{column-rank}(A) = n$?

This post is inspired by [Need help to prove the existence of set of linearly independent vectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341046/need-help-to-prove-the-existence-of-set-of-linearly-independent-vectors) Indeed, if one can answer positively my question, then it would imply the statement found in this linked post. Roughly speaking, the elements of the $j$-th column of $A$ belong to the vector space $S_j$. I can explain more why a positive solution of this problem gives a solution to the problem in the linked post if someone is interested.

Remark: the problem extends almost as is to matroids. Instead of assuming that the $v_{ij}$ belong to a vector space, one may instead assume that they belong to a matroid $M$. The rest of the post remains the same.

Comment: I answered your similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3487800/646723. I didn't check the differences between the questions to see if the answer can be extended, but it should help in any case.

Comment: @A.B., yes, I have a feeling a modification of your other answer should work here. I will try to modify your proof to see if it works for this case too also. Thank you again!

Comment: @A.B., note also that, if the proof can be extended/modified to this setting, then this would also give a proof of the linear algebra problem linked to in my post, which is what inspired me to ask these 2 problems anyway.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $m\geq n$? Also, how can column-rank(A) > n happen? (It seems equality is the maximum if I understand correctly)

Comment: yes, I am implicitly assuming that $m \geq n$. I should mention that in my post. You are right about the second point too. I wrote it in a way so as to remain as close as possible to the format of the original linear algebra problem, which inspired this problem. I edited the post now. Thank you.

Comment: I think the same proof (actually, even a bit simpler since you don't need to remove rows in this case) works also here. Try it, let me know if you want me to write the full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by induction on $n$; assume it's true for $k=n-1$ (note that $m\geq n$ so $m\geq k$).

Step 1: remove a column (say column $n$). Then row-rank$(A^{\{1,\dots,n-1\}})\geq n-1$ by the hypothesis so by the induction hypothesis has maximal column-rank $\{e_1,\dots, e_{n-1}\}$, with $e_i$ in column $i$. Since row-rank$(A)\geq n$, by matroid properties (e.g., rank) there is an element $v_{i,j}\in A$ such that $v_{i,j}=e_n\notin cl(e_1,\dots,e_{n-1})$. Clearly, if $j=n$ then we are done, so assume $j\neq n$; wlog we may assume $j=n-1$. Now $e_1,\dots, e_n$ are independent with $e_i$ in column $i$ for $i\leq n-1$ and $e_n$ is in column $n-1$ (this column has exactly $2$ $e_i$'s).

Step 2: remove the column $n-1$ from $A$. Then by Step 1 this sub-matrix $B=A^{\{1,\dots,n-2,n\}}$ contains $e_1,\dots, e_{n-2}$ in columns $1,\dots, n-2$ respectively. Additionally, by the hypothesis row-rank$(B)\geq n-1$ so by the induction hypothesis it has maximal column-rank $\{e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1}\}$, with $e'_i$ in column $i$ (column $n-1$ in $B$ is column $n$ in $A$; note that these $e'_i$'s might be completely different from the $e_i$'s). If $e_{n-1}\notin cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$ or $e_{n}\notin cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$ then we are again done (we can add this element for the missing column), so assume that $e_{n-1},e_n\in cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$.

Step 3: **Claim:** there is a column $c\leq n-2$ such that $e_c\neq e'_c$ and $\{e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1}\}\setminus \{e'_c\}\cup \{e_c\}$ is a maximal column-rank for $B$ (i.e., it is possible to replace $e'_c$ with $e_c$ in column $c$).

*Proof of claim:* $rank(e_1, \dots, e_n)=n>n-1=rank(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$ so there is $e_c\notin cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1})$, and by the assumption in Step 2 $c\neq n-1,n$. So $rank(\{e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1}\}\setminus \{e'_c\}\cup \{e_c\})=n-1$ by standard matroid properties.

Step 4: to conclude the proof we replace $\{e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1}\}$ in Step 2 with $\{e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-2}, e'_{n-1}\}\setminus \{e'_c\}\cup \{e_c\}$ in Step 3. If it still holds that $e_{n-1},e_n\in cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$ then we can reiterate Step 3 again and again (note that it will have to be a different $c$ each time since the $e_i$'s remain constant while the $e'_i$'s become the $e_i$'s), but at some point this process cannot continue further, since by rank considerations $cl(e_1,\dots, e_{n-2},e'_{n-1})$ cannot contain both $e_{n-1}$ and $e_n$ (i.e., in the extreme case this process stops after we replace all the $e'_i$'s with the $e_i$'s for $i\leq n-1$). At that point (when we cannot continue further) either $e_{n-1}\notin cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$ or $e_{n}\notin cl(e'_1,\dots, e'_{n-1})$, which means that we can add this element from column $n-1$ to form a maximal column-rank for $A$.

Comment: Thank you. And now the linear algebra problem is also solved, thanks to your proof of the problem here. Kindly see <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341046/need-help-to-prove-the-existence-of-set-of-linearly-independent-vectors> and please tell me if you agree with my proof (I think it is fine, but just to double check).